# Умножение матриц по Винограду

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы

Пытаюсь сделать умножение матриц по Винограду, но как-то не очень получается. Прошу помощи у вас. То что есть :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    const int max = 10;
    const int min =1;
    int arr1[n][n];
    int arr2[n][n];
    int arr3[n][n];
    std::vector <int> rowFactor;
    std::vector <int> columnFactor;

    int d = n/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
      {
        arr1[i][j] = rand()%(max-min+1) + min;
        arr2[i][j] = rand()%(max-min+1) + min;
      }
    }


    for(int i = 0 ;i<n;++i)
    {
      rowFactor.insert(rowFactor.end(), arr1[i][1]*arr1[i][2]);
      for(int j =0;j<d;++j)
      {
        rowFactor.insert(rowFactor.end(),rowFactor[i] + arr1[i][2*j - 1] * arr1[i][2*j]);
      }
    } 

    for(int i = 0 ;i<n;++i)
    {
      columnFactor.insert(columnFactor.end(), arr2[i][1]*arr2[i][2]);
      for(int j =0;j<d;++j)
      {
        columnFactor.insert(columnFactor.end(), columnFactor[i] +  arr2[2*j - 1][ i] * arr2[2*j][ i]);
      }
    }

    for(int i =0; i<n;++i)
    {
      for(int j =0;j<n;++j)
      {
        arr3[i][j] = -rowFactor[i] - columnFactor[j];

        for(int k = 0; k< d;k++)
        {
            arr3[i][j]=arr3[i][j]+(arr1[i][ 2*k-1]+arr2[2*k][j])*(arr1[i][ 2*k] + arr2[2*k-1][j]);
        }
      }
    }

    std::cout<<"\nresult\n"<<std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
      for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
         std::cout << " " << arr3[i][j];
      std::cout << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Даже что-то считает, но не правильно. Думаю в этой строке ошибка

```
arr3[i][j]=arr3[i][j]+(arr1[i][ 2*k-1]+arr2[2*k][j])*(arr1[i][ 2*k] + arr2[2*k-1][j]);
```

Comment: По-моему вы делаете немного неправильно. Судя по http://www.algolib.narod.ru/Math/Matrix.html , вам нужно делать не insert (rowFactor.insert(rowFactor.end(),rowFactor[i] + arr1[i][2*j - 1] * arr1[i][2*j]);) , а прибавление: rowFactor[i] = rowFactor[i] + arr1[i][2*j - 1] * arr1[i][2*j]; . Это первое, что бросилось в глаза. (аналогично для столбцов columnFactor)

Comment: Этот момент исправил, но теперь хоть появился варнинг "array subscript is below array bounds" в строке  arr3[i][j]= arr3[i][j] + (arr1[i][2*k-1]+arr2[2*k][j])*(arr1[i][2*k] + arr2[2*k-1][j]); в местах arr2[2*k-1][j] и arr1[i][2*k-1]

Comment: В этой формуле у вас точно ошибка, при k == 0 вы обращаетесь по индексу -1, что не есть хорошо (на это и ругается варнинг).

Comment: А подсказать можете как это исправить ? Саму ошибку понял, но как исправить чего-то не доходит до меня никак. Опирался то на алгоритм algolib.narod.ru/Math/Matrix.html

Comment: В указанной статье нумерация идёт от 1 до N, и при таких данных 2k - 1 в начале равно 1, что правильно. В нашем случае нумерация идёт от 0 до N - 1, учитывая это, думаю верной будет такая строка: arr3[i][j]=arr3[i][j]+(arr1[i][ 2*k]+arr2[2*k + 1][j])*(arr1[i][ 2*k + 1] + arr2[2*k][j]); PS. Перенёс исправление из комментария в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [статье о методе Винограда](https://algolib.narod.ru/Math/Matrix.html) нумерация идёт от 1 до N (там код написан на Паскале), и при таких данных 2k - 1 в начале равно 1, что правильно. В вашем случае нумерация идёт от 0 до N - 1, учитывая это, думаю верной будет такая строка:

```c
arr3[i][j] = arr3[i][j] + (arr1[i][2*k] + arr2[2*k + 1][j]) * (arr1[i][2*k + 1] + arr2[2*k][j]);
```

Comment: Черт, так стыдно. Думал о этом, но не сделал так. Спасибо! =) А такой еще вопрос, если умножать матрицу на матрицу обычным способом и данным, то ответ должен быть одинаковый, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Рад был помочь :) Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный, если он вам помог. Также было бы неплохо, если вы отредактируете вопрос, исправив в коде ошибку с insert'ами, чтобы в дальнейшем те, кто будет читать вопрос, не путались из-за них.